# what will happen if the input stream is invalid

Tags: c++, inputstream

What will happen if the input stream is invalid? For example, as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int value;
    while(!(cin>>value).eof());
}
```

If the entered sequence is : 1 2 3 q 4 5, the while will fall into endless loop when the cin scans 'q' and the value continues to be 3. 
My questions are:
1. Why can't cin ignore 'q' and proceed to scan 4?
2. What's the underlying implementation fo input stream? Are there any materials I can refer to ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Why can't cin ignore 'q' and proceed to scan 4?

You can if you want to. You could get that effect with the following:

```
int value;
while(std::cin>>value);
if (!std::cin)
{
    std::cin.clear(); // clear error state
    std::cin.ignore(); // ignore the q
    while(std::cin>>value); // read rest of values until 5
}
```

`std::cin >> value` just does not do that by default, as the behavior desired is different depending on the program. For many people it would be undesirable for `std::cin` to ignore a read failure and keep scanning. The default behavior allows you the programmer to decide what to do on failure.

Also, note that `eof()` is for checking for **end of file**. You should not use it to check if a read was successful or not. The common idiom would be:

```
while(std::cin>>value)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

> 2. What's the underlying implementation fo input stream? Are there any materials I can refer to ?

`std::cin` is a global static object and is defined like so:

```
extern std::istream cin;
```

In other words it is an instance of `std::basic_istream<char>` (std::istream is a typedef for it).

If you would like more information, here are some references:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin

https://github.com/cplusplus/draft

However, most likely you would benefit from a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

If you want to get into deep iostreams, I also recommend [these articles](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/C++Report.html).